# Stretch svg in flexbox to max height keeping aspect ratio

Tags: html, css, svg, flexbox

I have application layout as in this [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fogjxa8f/8/)

I need this svg however to stretch to full height of #contentComponent  while keeping aspect ratio, and sideComponent to take up remaining width accordingly. Is this even possible without using js?

Fiddle code below:

```html
<div id="appComponent">
  <div id="topComponent"></div>
  <div id="contentComponent">
    <div id="svgComponent">
      <div id="svgInlineWrapper">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 64 64" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin">
          <circle cx="32" cy="32" r="32" fill="blue" />
        </svg>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="sideComponent">
      <div id="sideScrollable">
        <div class="sideRow">
          Test1
        </div>
        <div class="sideRow">
          Test2
        </div>
        <div class="sideRow">
          Test3
        </div>
        <div class="sideRow">
          Test4
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#appComponent {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ff0000;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#topComponent {
  flex: 0 0 40px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #00ff00;
}

#contentComponent {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-content: stretch;
}

#svgComponent {
  height: 100%;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  background-color: #aa00aa;
}

#svgInlineWrapper {
  height: 100%;
}

#svgInlineWrapper svg {
  height: 100%;
}

#sideComponent {
  position: relative;
  flex: 1 1 200px;
  background-color: #0000ff;
}

#sideScrollable {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.sideRow {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

EDIT:

It looks like it works completely different in chrome and in firefox. In firefox it stretches to 100% height, but it does not seem to work in chrome.

Answer (score 1):

Update css below change `100%`to `100vh`to stretch with aspect ratio.

```
#svgInlineWrapper svg {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#appComponent {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ff0000;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#topComponent {
  flex: 0 0 40px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #00ff00;
}

#contentComponent {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-content: stretch;
}

#svgComponent {
  height: 100%;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  background-color: #aa00aa;
}

#svgInlineWrapper {
  height: 100%;
}

#svgInlineWrapper svg {
  height: 100vh;
}

#sideComponent {
  position: relative;
  flex: 1 1 200px;
  background-color: #0000ff;
}

#sideScrollable {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.sideRow {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="appComponent">

  <div id="topComponent"></div>
  <div id="contentComponent">
    <div id="svgComponent">
      <div id="svgInlineWrapper">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 64 64" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin">
          <circle cx="32" cy="32" r="32" fill="blue" />
        </svg>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="sideComponent">
      <div id="sideScrollable">
        <div class="sideRow">
          Test1
        </div>
        <div class="sideRow">
          Test2
        </div>
        <div class="sideRow">
          Test3
        </div>
        <div class="sideRow">
          Test4
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I cannot set svg to 100vh, because it then overflows for the height of #topComponent.

Answer (score 1):

Try `min-height` instead of `height`.

```
#svgComponent {
  min-height: 100%;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  background-color: #aa00aa;
}
```